# Searching a field in SQL to see if it contains a python variable

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I am using the Canari Framework to build a series of transforms within Malteog that scan a MySQL database and return the results as entities.

I've got the entire thing working bar the LIKE operator within the SQL statement. Here's the code:

```
#===========================================================================
# Request and set target from graph

target = (request.entity.value)

#===========================================================================
# Extract message column and check against target entity

statement = (
    "SELECT * FROM tableT.TTO WHERE Text LIKE %(tq)s"
)

cursor.execute(statement, { 'tq': target })

results = cursor.fetchall()

#===========================================================================
# Create response entities based on SQL output

for r in results:

    e = getTTO(target)
    e.From = r[0]
    e.Text = r[1]
    e.date = r[2]
    e.iconurl = 'http://local.paterva.com/phrase.png'
    response += e
```

It works, but it's only returning matches that are exact. I need it to check the TEXT column to see if the entries contain any mention of the variable "target". I spent the best part of a day getting the python variable passed in, but I can't get it to return anything other than an exact match.

Comment: You are probably looking for [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL LIKE operator needs special "wildcard" markers ("%" in MySQL) before and/or after the value (depending on if you want a "starts with", "endswith" or "contains" search). You have to add those wildcards around your argument, ie:

```
cursor.execute(statement, {'tq': "%{}%".format(target)})
```

Also note that `cursor.fetchall()` will load your whole resultset in memory, which is asking for `MemoryError`. `cursor` objects are iterables and it's safer to use them that way:

```
cursor.execute(statement, {'tq': "%{}%".format(target)})
for row in cursor:
    do_something_with(row)
```

Comment: I see! Many thanks. I dont spend a lot of time with SQL, so I am just getting into the nuts and bolts. As with most projects... there isn't space for "learning time". Thats cleared it up though. Great stuff.